# How to manage roles in symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony

I have a web application where i have 5 level of users like

1. Administrator
2. OrganisationHead
3. LocalCOmpany head
4. Teacher
5. parents
6. students

Now every userwill have different landing page or with some more or less tabs or features.

Now i want to know that is it i only make it as one Entity and then Roles in different entity so that i can simplify the login process

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle? If so, it already comes with one entity that can be associated with specific roles.

Comment: I am coding my own User bundle. I am new to symfony , i find it hard to do customization of already coded bundle

Comment: I see, then you want to create one entity (User) then create roles as one of its fields. Then in your controller, you can just control which landing pages to show depending on the user's role.

Comment: Can i assign which menus/tabs to appear on which roles

Comment: Yes, it's very simple. It can be controlled in the twig template. For example, you can pass the user role into the template, then in the twig, just specify which tabs to show for that specific role using if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would go about it

Your controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    return $this->render('YourBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array('user_role' => $user->getRole()));
}
```

Twig:

```
{% if user_role == "administrator" %}
Menu 1, menu 2, menu3
{% elseif user_role == "organizationhead" %}
Menu 1, Menu 4
{% elseif user_role == "etc" %}
Menu 5
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the twig function `is_granted()` instead and let the Security component handle the roles. This have a few advances such as nested roles definitions. You can find a lot more information at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles.

I strongly urge you to go that way!

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR') %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```